# Activity based authorization in Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

We are using Dropwizard auth package and JWT for authenticating and authorizing in our shopfloor management app. The rule is that only someone with MANAGER role can checkout tool from a bin belonging to his/her team. So, we've code like below:

```
@RolesAllowed("MANAGER")
public Response checkoutTools(@Auth User u, @QueryParam Bin b)
```

In the authorization code, if the jwt token has manager, we allow them.

As always happens, the rules changed. We want to make sure the manager can checkout from the bin "belongs" to him/her. The authorizer code do not have Bin information. Of course, I do not like to reauthorize again in the "checkoutTools" method, if possible.
In other words, I need to authorize based on the activity that happens inside the resource. Is there a way to implement activity based authorization in Dropwizard?